# ASP.NET Core - adding/removing authentication schemes to/from AuthorizationPolicy at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

My ASP.NET Core 8 App uses multiple authentication schemes that I need to be able to turn on/off at runtime. Adding/removing authentication schemes to/from the `IAuthenticationSchemeProvider` at runtime works fine - I've used [this sample](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/5a6b6c90b6e32ecab4975c546228cc63199f168b/src/AuthSamples/samples/DynamicSchemes/Controllers/AuthController.cs) at a starting point. However, I need my default authorization to contain multiple schemes since I'm using multiple schemes for Jwt (local auth in my app, and ADFS). So, my `ConfigureServices(IServicecollection services)` contains this:

```
    var authPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(Contants.MyCustomAuthScheme);
    
    services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
        .SetDefaultPolicy(authPolicyBuilder.Build());
```

Now, `Constants.MyCustomAuthScheme` may not be enabled by default, so the second call to `AddAuthenticationSchemes` would be commented out. And now I need to be able to add this auth scheme at runtime. I found I can access my `AuthorizationPolicy` at runtime from `IAuthorizationPolicyProvider.GetDefaultPolicy`, and while `AuthorizationPolicy` exposes the `AuthenticationSchemes` property, it's read-only. I figure for enabling the additional scheme, I might create another `AuthorizationPolicy` when needed and using `AuthorizationPolicy.Combine` to combine my default authorization policy with another that is the same except for the scheme. But, what if I want to disable a scheme at runtime?

Comment: Based on the sample, we could remove the Scheme, if you don't want to add it, why you don't use it to remove it after the application started. Like, read the appsetting.json file to remove some Scheme.

Comment: Do you have an example on how to remove the scheme? Keep in mind we're talking about the scheme on the `AuthorizationPolicy`, not adding/removing schemes to/From the `IAuthenticationSchemeProvider` - the latter works, but the former, I'm not seeing a way. And just to make sure, we're not talking at startup, we're talking once the app is up - then there's no `AuthorizationPolicyBuilder`, it has been build and we have the `AuthorizationPolicy` which has the schemes as read-only collection

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally found a solution. Combining `AuthorizationPolicy` was no options as you cannot modify/replace AuthorizationPolicies returned by the `IAuthorizationPolicyProvider`. So I had to go all in, writing my own implementation of `IAuthorizationPolicyProvider` instead. I basically copied the [DefaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider.cs) and added two methods to it:

```
public async Task EnableScheme(string scheme)
{
    var defaultPolicy = await GetDefaultPolicyAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (!defaultPolicy.AuthenticationSchemes.Contains(scheme))
    {
        List<string> newSchemes = [.. defaultPolicy.AuthenticationSchemes];
        newSchemes.Add(scheme);
        var newPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy(defaultPolicy.Requirements, newSchemes);
        _options.DefaultPolicy = newPolicy;
    }
}

public async Task DisableScheme(string scheme)
{
    var defaultPolicy = await GetDefaultPolicyAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (defaultPolicy.AuthenticationSchemes.Contains(scheme))
    {
        List<string> newSchemes = [.. defaultPolicy.AuthenticationSchemes];
        newSchemes.Remove(scheme);
        var newPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy(defaultPolicy.Requirements, newSchemes);
        _options.DefaultPolicy = newPolicy;
    }
}
```

I'm only using the default policy, you could easily do it for the backup policy, too. If you need it for all policies, then you're out of luck since AuhthorizationOptions don't expose the `PolicyMap`.